# Start/Stop services using JNA

Tags: java, winapi, windows-services, jna

I am writing a utility to start and stop windows services.  The program will be distributed across many computers with differing levels of user privileges so I don't want to use the command line. I've tried using JNA,

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32ServiceManager;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winsvc;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class WindowsServices {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try
      {

        // TODO code application logic here
         W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();

        W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("uvnc_service", Winsvc.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP);
        service.stopService();
        service.close();   
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }


    }
}
```

When I run the program I get the following error

com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid.
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32ServiceManager.openService(W32ServiceManager.java:77)
    at windowsservices.WindowsServices.main(WindowsServices.java:26)

Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: This is pretty cool, didn't know you could control the Windows services this easily with JNA.

Comment: The only problem I found with this method is that when you try to stop services you have to provide extra try/catch blocks because some services take a while to go from running to stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion the author of the question found the error.

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32ServiceManager;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winsvc;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class WindowsServices {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();
            serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS); 
            W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("uvnc_service", Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
            service.startService();
            service.close();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error was that the code didn't open the Service Control Manager. I was looking on MSDN and found the process that I needed to follow. I also chanced the permission value, that might also of caused a failure.

Answer (score 0):

We use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` and then execute the command

> cmd /c net start

to start services and

> cmd /c net stop

to stop services.

Of course you have to know the service names (and in our case it is DB2 we are after). But this has worked for us.